# convert strings from special char to no special char

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, boto

I am using python 2.7.  If i have a string assigned to the name variable like below

```
name = "Test with-name and_underscore"
```

How can i convert this into a string that can be assigned to the name variable

```
name = "TestWithNameAndUnderscore"
```

Is Regular expression the way to go or does python have any built functions to do that....

So what i am looking for is, when a string comes in with underscore or dashes or space or any special char in it, that get converted to the same thing but No underscore/dashes/space/special char and the initial letter of that word would have start with upper case, so like "test name - is this_here" to "TestNameIsThisHere".

And if there is no space or no special chars then dont do anything. So if the string is "Helloworld", to skip it and move on.

Reason why i am doing this is, i am writing something for AWS using python boto and there is a naming restriction on what the resources can be called. It cannot be non alphanumeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> name = "Test with-name and_underscore"
>>> print(''.join(x.capitalize() for x in re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]').split(name)))
TestWithNameAndUnderscore
```

You can strip leading digits off as well, if that is needed.  Here is a slightly more robust example that will do that and insure that the resulting string is not empty:

```
>>> import re
>>> def fix_id(s, split=re.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|^[0-9]+').split):
...     result = ''.join(x.capitalize() for x in split(s))
...     if not result:
...         raise ValueError('Invalid ID (empty after edits)')
...     return result
... 
>>> fix_id("Test with-name and_underscore")
'TestWithNameAndUnderscore'
>>> fix_id("123 Test 456 with-name and_underscore 789")
'Test456WithNameAndUnderscore789'
>>> fix_id("Thisshouldbeunmolested")
'Thisshouldbeunmolested'
>>> fix_id('123')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in fix_id
ValueError: Invalid ID (empty after edits)
```

Note that neither of these will guarantee the uniqueness of your identifiers, e.g. "Mary-Sue" and "mary sue" will map to the same identifier.  If you need these to map to different identifiers, you can add a cache dictionary, where you map symbols and add a suffix if necessary.

Comment: I think that might not work...see below   >>> name = "d-12312340_work"
>>> print(''.join(x.capitalize() for x in re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]').split(name)))
DWork
>>>

Comment: @maxscalf  I added 0-9.  However, if it were to start with 0-9, this would be a problem.  If you anticipate that happening it would require more code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without Regex using the isalnum() function in Python.

```
name = "Test with-name and_underscore"
new_name = ''.join(name for name in string if e.isalnum())
```

Ofcourse, if you do insist on using regex this is possible too by replacing isalnum() with the appropriate regex function.

Answer (score 1):

I know a stupid way to do it!

```
name.replace('_',' ').replace('-',' ')
name = name.title().replace(' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible smaller re approach would be to use the following:

```
  import re
   string = '123 this is a test_of the-sub method 33'
   varString = re.sub('_?-? ?', '', string)
```

it should return

```
>>> sub('_?-? ?','',string) 
'123thisisatestofthesubmethod33'
```

If you are trying to use it as a variable name though you likely will run into some troubles, such as too long (pep8 compliance) or other foreign characters such as !?$% etc....in which the isalpha method above may help with.   I'd be careful us trusting the value of the string to become a variable name and wrap some constraints to avoid any kind of overflow.